# PIC18F25K80 and SD card integration

Tags: sd-card, pic

I am using a PIC18F25K80 microporcessor and i want to store data into a SD card. Which libraries should I to implement data transfer between the PIC and SD card. I am not sure if I can use the MLA library for file I/O.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use **[SPI Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus)** to communicate with **SD card**. There is one hardware SPI module available with `PIC18F25K80` micro-controller. You don't need to depend upon `MLA`. You can create your own SPI driver, but you just need to understands basics for `SPI communication`. [This link](http://elm-chan.org/docs/mmc/mmc_e.html) will surely help you to understand guidelines for interfacing `PIC` with `SD Card`